PySeriel - Accept (write) confirmation prompt from network sensor
I'm working on collecting a few common configuration steps for jumping network sensors via the console port.
Most of what I'll tried is working great, however I have noticed that if I send a command that requires user confirmation my write statment isn't working as intended.
As you can see from this putty example
# Login sequence cut
hostname# show uptime
uptime "51 days, 20 hours, 36 mins and 2 seconds"
hostname# config terminal
Entering configuration mode terminal
hostname(config)# system contact "John Doe"
hostname(config)# copy running-config startup-config
Are you sure? [no,yes] yes

OK. Saved running-config to startup-config.
hostname(config)# exit
hostname#

My script works fin until we reach the Are you sure?
hostname(config)# copy running-config startup-config
Are you sure?
Aborted: by user
hostname(config)# yes
-----------------------^
syntax error: unknown command

It almost appers as a halt command (\r or ctrl+c ) is sent before the yes write is initiated ? Does any one know if this prompts back from a serial device is handled differently ?
import serial
import time

def read_until_prompt(prompt, timeout=10, user_input=None):
    buffer = ""
    end_time = time.time() + timeout
    while time.time() < end_time:
        if ser.in_waiting:
            buffer += ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode("utf-8")
            if prompt in buffer:
                if user_input is not None:
                    command = user_input.encode("utf-8") + b"\r\n"
                    ser.write(command)
                    print("\n--Current buffer--\n" + buffer)
                return buffer
        time.sleep(0.1)
    raise TimeoutError(f"Did not find prompt: {prompt}")


ser = serial.Serial(
    port=com_interface,
    baudrate=115200,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    timeout=1,
    xonxoff=False,  # No flow control
    rtscts=False,  # No flow control
    dsrdtr=False,  # No flow control
)

try:
    STANDARD_PROMT = "#"
    CONFIG_PROMT = "(config)#"
    # Initial connection sequence
    time.sleep(2)  # Initial delay, to allow for initialization
    ser.write(b"\x03")  # reset any activity
    
    read_until_prompt("login:")
    ser.write(b"john\r\n")  # Username
    read_until_prompt("Password:")
    ser.write(f"{password}\r\n".encode("utf-8"))

    # Workes just fine
    read_until_prompt(STANDARD_PROMT, user_input="show uptime")
    read_until_prompt(STANDARD_PROMT, user_input="config terminal")
    read_until_prompt(CONFIG_PROMT, user_input=f'system contact "John Doe"')

    # Save config to startup
    read_until_prompt(CONFIG_PROMT, user_input=f'copy running-config startup-config')
        # a confirmation promped is shown 'Are you sure? [yes/no]', buffer shows 'Are you sure?'
    read_until_prompt("Are you sure?", user_input='yes')

    # Additional attempt
    ser.write(b'copy running-config startup-config\r\n')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ser.write(b'yes\r\n')
    time.sleep(15)

    read_until_prompt(CONFIG_PROMT, user_input="exit")
finally:
        ser.close()



Shouldn't that be: read_until_prompt("Are you sure?", user_input=f'yes') ?

Yuo are right, that was just a copy/paste error. when i pulled this out of a larger script. Adjusted

You should probably read the whole prompt read_until_prompt("Are you sure? [no,yes] "..., as the remote might be doing a flush of the serial line just after the prompt to ensure any typeahead is cleared out.  You may even need to add a small sleep after matching the prompt, in case the flush is slow to take effect.
